# Why derived class object automatically calls the parent class constructor with no argument?

Tags: c++

Why in C++ when derived class object is created, then it automatically calls the parent class constructor with no argument?

Comment: Did you specify a constructor in the derived class that does otherwise?  If not that is how the language works.  You should post an [mcve]

Comment: It calls exactly that constructor that you instructed your derived-class constructor to use. By default that's the default constructor.

Comment: Which parent constructor would you like to be called?

Answer (score 2):

Question:

> Why in C++ when derived class object is created, then it automatically calls the parent class constructor with no argument?

Answer:  Because the standard says so (emphasis mine).

> **12.6.2 Initializing bases and members**
>
> 8 In a non-delegating constructor, if a given non-static data member or base class is not designated by a *mem-initializer-id* (including the case where there is no *mem-initializer-list* because the constructor has no *ctor-initializer*) and the entity is not a virtual base class of an abstract class (10.4), then
>
> — if the entity is a non-static data member that has a *brace-or-equal-initializer*, the entity is initialized as specified in 8.5;
> — otherwise, if the entity is a variant member (9.5), no initialization is performed;
> — otherwise, **the entity is default-initialized** (8.5).